when using: node app.js to instantiate the opening of your page inside the cmd line terminal what is the command to close out the page?
Well just a little rusty coding!  Have intermediate knowledge and really this particular tutorial is using different stack( express, ejs, mongoose, and really i am only familiar with fundimental express knowledge).  However, I am do not know how to close out the instance when using cmd line prompt cmd: node app.js to instantiate the opening of the project page that all!
I tried cntrl c?   did not get prompt to close port: 3000, was hoping it would be the cmd or method used to close an instance using this teck stack or rather using express?
